# Is this the correct way of adding parammeters to constructor in Dagger 2?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

**Context**

Recenty I started investigating about dependency injection and Dagger 2. It looks a pretty good library but it seems a bit confusing to me. There are some situations in which I don't know exactly how to proceed.

**What have I tried**

I have created a simple Android app that creates a Client and its Dependency and do some (dummy) work. These are the classes:

Client.java

```
public class Client {

    private Dependency dep;

    @Inject
    public Client(Dependency dep) {
        this.dep = dep;
    }

    public void work() {
        System.out.println("Client working");
        dep.doWork();
    }
}
```

Dependency.java

```
public class Dependency {

    @Inject
    public Dependency() {
    }

    public void doWork() {
        System.out.println("Dependency working");
    }
}
```

Following some tutorials I created a couple of Module classes:

DependencyModule.java

```
@Module
public class DependencyModule {

    @Provides
    Dependency provideDependency() {
        return new Dependency();
    }
}
```

ClientModule.java

```
@Module
public class ClientModule {

    @Provides
    Client provideClient(Dependency dep) {
        return new Client(dep);
    }

}
```

And also the Component interface:

```
@Component(modules = {ClientModule.class})
public interface ClientComponent {

    Client provideClient();

}
```

This works fine. From my activity I can do the following and it works:

```
ClientComponent clientComp = DaggerClientComponent
                .builder()
                .clientModule(new ClientModule())
                .build();

Client client = clientComp.provideClient();
client.work();
```

**Problem**

I understand how to inject dependencies in a client (at least I think so). But how I add parameters into the constructor of a client/dependency?

I mean, what if I would wanted to add some int parameters to my objects? Something as simple as this:

Client.java

```
public class Client {

    int id;
    Dependency dep;

    @Inject
    public Client(int id, Dependency dep) {
        this.id = id;
        this.dep = dep;
    }

    public void work() {
        System.out.println("id: " + id + " Client working");
        dep.doWork();
    }
}
```

Dependency.java

```
public class Dependency {

    private int id;

    @Inject
    public Dependency(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void doWork() {
        System.out.println("id: " + id + " Dependency working");
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** 
The following code is what I've tried. So I'm not sure about its correctness.

So, as the objects has new parameters in their constructor the Modules have to change:

DependencyModule.class

```
public class DependencyModule {

    @Provides
    Dependency provideDependency() {
        return new Dependency(id);
    }
}
```

ClientModule.class

```
@Module
public class ClientModule {

    @Provides
    Client provideClient(int id, Dependency dep) {
        return new Client(id, dep);
    }

}
```

**Question**

How do I use that new Modules? I haven't found a way to pass the id to that methods. The only way I get it to work is by passing it in the Module constructor and removing it from the `provide` method. This way:

```
@Module
public class ClientModule {

    private int id;

    public ClientModule(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Provides
    Client provideClient(Dependency dep) {
        return new Client(id, dep);
    }

}
```

Same approach in the `DependencyModule.java`.

This way, adding the DependencyModule.class in the ClientComponent interface I can do something like:

```
ClientComponent clientComp = DaggerClientComponent
                .builder()
                .clientModule(new ClientModule(clientId))
                .dependencyModule(new DependencyModule(dependencyId))
                .build();

Client client = clientComp.provideClient();
client.work();
```

Is that the correct way of doing that?

Is there a better way of getting the same effect?

Am I committing crimes against DI principle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two basic ways to get Dagger to provide an instance of a class:

1. Add `@Inject` to a constructor, and put the class's dependencies in as constructor arguments.
2. Add a `@Provides`-annotated method to a `@Module`-annotated class, and install that module into your `@Component`.

You only need to use one method for each class. So in your first example, `Client` and `Dependency` are fine as is; you don't also need `ClientModule` and `DependencyModule`.

Once you add the `int` dependency, now you do need a module, because there's no class to `@Inject`. The module just needs to provide that `int`, so something like this would work:

```
@Module
public class ClientIdModule {
  private final clientId;

  public ClientIdModule(int clientId) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
  }

  @Provides
  static int clientId() {
    return clientId;
  }
}
```

Now if you install `ClientIdModule` into your component, you'll be able to get a `Client` which has the right ID, and its `Dependency` will as well.